# Distinct sum in excel/sheets pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot

Let's say I have some data I generated through a window function (lifetime_clicks)

I want to know in excel or google sheets pivot table if can get the % of lifetime clicks come from today_clicks (hour_clicks / lifetime_clicks)

```
user_id date hour_clicks lifetime_clicks
     1   02      30            90000
     1   02      2             90000
     1.  02      200           90000
     1.  03      4544          90000
```

I would like to group the data on date and sum(hour_clicks) and divide that by 90000, but everytime I enter lifetime_clicks to the calculated field, it sums the data.

is there a way to distinct sum(lifetime_clicks) to prevent such a thing from occurring?

Comment: You'll need to use a DAX measure in Power Pivot.

Comment: Or use power query

Comment: OR add a helper column to your data before creating your Pivot table

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*I would like to group the data on date and sum(hour_clicks) and divide that by 90000*

Easiest option is adding a HELPER column, like my column E in image above. Formula is just `=C2/D2`

Second option, if you are going to divide **always** by 90.000, then you could use a Calculated field.

[image]

To be honest, I think easiest way would be helper column.